# Laravel-Vue Http request with a url that redirect

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, decode

The implementation was decode the image to Base64, and the image link is from google storage, when using browser the link will get the information of a user that is sign in from google, and check if that user is allowed to access the image in google storage.
But the problem is `Http::get` is still inprocess of redirection of getting the user details then its being decoded which is wrong is should finish all the process.
How to fix this?

```
  try{
            
            $imageUrl = 'https://urlOfGoogleStorageLink';
        
        $response = Http::get($imageUrl);
     
    
            $imageData = $response->body();
    
            // Convert image data to base64
            $base64Image = base64_encode($imageData);

            // Create a data URI for the image
            $dataUri = 'data:image/png;base64,' . $base64Image;

            return response()->json($dataUri,200);

        }catch(Exception $error){
            dd( $error);
        }
```

Decode the image link from google stoge image